How to pass value between steps? 'Context' object has no attribute
Code:
@then('the user should see the generated survey code')
def step_then_user_sees_generated_survey_code(context):
    context.survey_code = context.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#survey_code").get_attribute('value')
    print(22222222,context.survey_code)
    assert context.survey_code is not None


@given('the user has a generated survey code')
def step_given_user_has_generated_survey_code(context):
    print(444444444444444,context.survey_code)
    assert context.survey_code is not None

In line:
print(22222222,context.survey_code)

I can get a value.
But in line:
print(444444444444444,context.survey_code)

I received an error:
  AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'survey_code'

My purpose is to pass the survey_code value from @then step to @given step

Try to set the @then in survey_code attribute in context object and @given similary.
@then('the user should see the generated survey code')
def step_then_user_sees_generated_survey_code(context):
    context.survey_code = context.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#survey_code").get_attribute('value')
    print(22222222, context.survey_code)
    assert context.survey_code is not None

@given('the user has a generated survey code')
def step_given_user_has_generated_survey_code(context):
    assert hasattr(context, 'survey_code'), "Survey code attribute is not set in context"
    print(444444444444444, context.survey_code)
    assert context.survey_code is not None

Hopefully this will resolve your error. Its all about how you properly setup up the context. Share more detailed logs if error presists.
